# A class within a class - via an Initialiser Lists: NOT able to update a variable

Tags: arduino-uno, c++, library, class

My test are based on the blog of http://arduinoetcetera.blogspot.be/2011/01/classes-within-classes-initialiser.html.

Because I would like to use this idea, I tried with a simple idea, after the instance is created just ***update*** a value.

But for some reason, the code compiles perfectly and there seems to be no error with the ***update*** method, but it **DOES NOT UPDATE** the variable.

But my output on the serial monitor show that the number (volatile int) doesn't update.

```
Object of class First has value - Number: 6
Object of class Second has value - Number: 13
Object of class Second has value - Double: 26
Object of class Second has value - Update: [0] - 20  // <--
- - 
Object of class First has value - Number: 6
Object of class Second has value - Number: 13        // <--
Object of class Second has value - Double: 26
Object of class Second has value - Update: [1] - 70
- - 
Object of class First has value - Number: 6
Object of class Second has value - Number: 13
```

code - MAIN :  First thing(**6**, **13**); 
[edited on request of @Mark Smith]

```
#include "First.h"
First thing(6, 13);
...
int newValue;
...
int ledPins[] = {
  20, 70, 45, 68, 543, 321
}; // an array of pin numbers to which LEDs are attached
int pinCount = 6; // the number of pins (i.e. the length of the array)
bool plus=true;
int index=-1;
void loop() {
  Serial.print("Object of class First has value - Number: ");
  Serial.println(thing.Number());
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Object of class Second has value - Number: ");
  Serial.println(thing.getSecond().Number());
  Serial.print("Object of class Second has value - Double: ");
  Serial.println(thing.getSecond().Double());
  ...  
  Serial.print("Object of class Second has value - Update: [");
  if ( plus && index == (pinCount-1) ) {
    plus=!plus;
  }
  if ( !plus && index == 0 ) {
    plus=!plus;
  }
  // change + <--> -
  (plus) ? index++ : index--;
  newValue=ledPins[index];
  Serial.print(index,DEC);
  Serial.print("] - ");
  Serial.println(newValue, DEC);
  thing.getSecond().Update(newValue);
  Serial.println("- - ");
```

code - FIRST

```
#include "First.h" 
...
First::First(int firstNumber, int secondNumber) : widget(secondNumber) {
  itsNumber = firstNumber;
}
int First::Number() {
  return itsNumber;
}
Second First::getSecond() {
  return widget;
}
```

code - SECOND : void Second::Update(int **newNumber**)

```
#include "Second.h"
...
volatile int itsNumber;
Second::Second(int newNumber) {
  itsNumber = newNumber;
}
void Second::Update(int newNumber) {
  itsNumber = newNumber;
}
int Second::Number() {
  return itsNumber;
}
int Second::Double() {
  return itsNumber*2;
}
```

For the complete code
https://github.com/droopy4u/ARDUINO
 [- https://github.com/droopy4u/ARDUINO/tree/master/ClassWithClasses -](https://github.com/droopy4u/ARDUINO/tree/master/ClassWithClasses)

Comment: Could you post the actual code please? The part you've posted doesn't show the problem part. It's not good to rely on external links because they might disappear, and in your case it's not obvious (enough that I can be bothered to work out) which of the two very similar sets of files in your git repo you're using. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an Arduino specific question, its general C/C++ *BUT* it is quite an important problem that lots of novice programmers have so I don't think it should be moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even without the real code, I think the problem is with the function First::Second().

You need to understand what happens in C++ when values are passed as parameters.  The are passed by value by default, this means a *COPY* of the value is passed into the function, you can modify the parameter all you like but when you return those changes are lost.

There are two exceptions to this, the first is pointers.  When you pass in a pointer you can modify what is pointed to but you still can't modify the pointer, because that is a copy.  If you want to modify the pointer then you need a pointer to a pointer `int** ptr_to_ptr`.

The other exception is a reference.  In this case the function can modify the parent function's variable.  This is more efficient in terms of memory.

So you have:

```
int AddOne(int value) {++value; return value};   // 5 == AddOne(5);
int AddOne (int value) {return value+1};         // 6 == AddOne(5); - doesn't modify the parameter.
int AddOne(int* pValue) {(*value)+1; return *value;}//6 == AddOne(5); - Pointer 
int AddOne(int& value){++value; return value;}   // 6 == AddOne(5); - Referance
int AddOne(const int& value){++value; return value;} // Compiler error, modifying const value.
```

So why it is First::Second() causing the problem?  Well the same rules apply to return values as to parameters and you are returning a copy of the value `widget` so you then modify that copy and then dispose of it.  So this is what you need to fix the problem.

```
Second& First::getSecond()
{
    return widget;
}
```

EDIT : Its not clear in the preceding text but you don't need `getSecond()` to return a reference if you are not altering the value of `widget` so `getDouble()` will return the expected value because it is working form a copy of the original and not storing any changes.  However `update()` will not work as expected because the result of `getSecond()` goes out of scope (gets disposed of) once the call is complete.  The changes its made are not save to the original because it is working on a copy.

Comment: PART1
Thank you very much for response ... first I was thinking and tried the same thing but then in the Class with the variable, but most probably I did something wrong, because of the compiler errors.

But I created a *First.cpp* and a *First.h* file - library. - so is it then not an instance?
I try to understand it ... but find it hard to solve the problem.

Comment: PART2
Tried your suggestion
by 
**`Second& First::getSecond()`** as well **`Second &First::getSecond()`**


->
 *prototype ... does not match any in class 'First'*.

I'm a beginner, but if I call the method `thing.getSecond().Double()` then it returns the correct data ` int Second::Double(){
  return itsNumber*2;
}` as 26. But it seems that the update is not working well, do you maybe have an other suggestion?

Comment: ... thanks for your quick response and effort Because I have not enough reputation I'm not able to vote on your answer. Even not enough privilege to edit my own comment. Thank you very much.

Comment: The position of the space doesn't matter in this case, but I prefer `Second& First::getSecond()` because it makes it a bit clearer that it is Second you are referencing.  The error `prototype ... does not match any in class 'First'` means you need to change it in the .h and the .cpp file.

Comment: Part 2 :)  without using `Second& First::getSecond()` `thing.getSecond().Double()` will return 26 because you are taking a copy of `widget` and returning that copy and then reading the value from that copy before disposing of it.      When you do `thing.getSecond().Update(8)` you are getting a copy of widget, changing the value *in that copy* and then disposing of the copy.  The value in widget was never changed and this is why it is not working as you think it would.    I understand it can be difficult to comprehend so in every day terms...

Comment: Imagine that you have a letter.  You take a photocopy of the letter.  On this copy you underline the address the letter was sent from.  You then throw the photocopy away.  Where has the underlined text gone on the original?
  If we use a reference `&` to the object (or a pointer) it means that there was no photocopy you changed the original letter and you still have the underlining.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: Now it is clear ... just an other COPY of the widget.

Thank you very much ...

An other question ... were you may be know the answer to let (the two) classes communicate with each other ... what is the best way to do it.
Event handlers ... or ... what are you recommendations?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, also its another question so I think you should raise it as a separate question.  I'll keep looking for it.

Comment: mean something ... delegate ... "Observer" - and method notifyObservers of "Observable" ... But gonna search on google ... thanks any way ... Happy Hollidays

Answer (score 0):

@MATT,
with trying to get the address of variable via

```
    const long SERIAL_SPEED=38400;//baud rate of the serial communication

//global variable
    int a = 15;
    int *b=a;

void infoVar(){
    Serial.print("\n\n");
    Serial.print(" a -  ");  Serial.println(a, DEC );
    Serial.print("*b -  ");  Serial.println(*b, DEC );  // dereferencing
    Serial.print("\n");

    Serial.print("int  b - ");  Serial.println( (int) b, DEC );   // ???
    // This is the content of the pointer variable b
    Serial.print("int &b - ");  Serial.println( (int) &b, DEC );  // address of memory location where b is stored
    Serial.print("int &a - ");  Serial.println( (int) &a, DEC );  // address of memory location where a is stored 
}

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(SERIAL_SPEED);      // open the serial port at SERIAL_SPEED bps:

    Serial.println("Started : ### reference_pointer ###\n\n");


// *** :  when uncomment next line : the value b = 123
//b=123

    *b=a;
    infoVar();

    a=235;
    *b=a;
    infoVar();

    a=1928;
    *b=a;
    infoVar();

    }

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

OUTPUT

```
 a -  15
*b -  15

int  b – 15
        // don't understand here that it is 15
            //thought that is would be the the address of the variable 'a'
            // it seems that it keeps the first initiated value??? ***
int &b - 676
int &a - 256


 a -  235
*b -  235

int  b - 15
int &b - 676
int &a - 256


 a -  1928
*b -  1928

int  b - 15
int &b - 676
int &a - 256
```